# QGIS symbology for line layer

Tags: qgis, symbology

I want to create the following symbology for a line layer.
But I don´t know how to create the black part for my line.

[image]

It´s a pink line in the background, with a black rectangles on top of it. The beginn and end of the rectangles are longer then the rectangle. The black geometry repeats itself every 2cm.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What would be your pattern repetition ? Have the spaces between your symbols anything to do with the vertices of your object ? Tell a bit more ...

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Multiple styles are needed together.

1) the background: a solid line with a large width
2) a simple line, with a custom dash pattern. Set the dash length to the length of the inner rectangle, and the space as the space between them. Take note of the total length (referred as `TL` below) of a the pattern (dash + space).
3) a marker line, with a simple marker being a vertical line. The markers should be displayed every `TL`.
4) a second marker line, with a simple marker being a vertical line. The markers should be displayed every `TL` with an offset being the length of the dash.

Now you can play with the lines thickness. You may have to adjust the makers placement to cover the dashed line segments (its thickness is like a buffer, in every direction)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help :)